# Excel: How to add an index that ignores empty cells

Tags: excel

I am given an excel table. I want to include an additional column which simply contains an index. The column to the right of this index will have some text in it, or be empty. I want to have an index whenever the cell to its right is NOT empty.

Example:

```
1    Some Text
2    Some Text


3    Some Text

4    Some Text
```

I was hoping to achieve this by applying the following formula:

```
=IF(B7="";"";MAX(A4:A6)+1)
```

The cells given in the `MAX()` function are all the cells that come before the current cell. This formula works fine, but unfortunately only whenever there are not more than 3 empty cells in between. 
Can I make this formula work for an arbitrary amount of empty cells in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with data Like:

[image]

In **A1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="";"";1)
```

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="";"";1+MAX($A$1:A1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The formula in `A1` I've used is:

```
`=IF(AND(B1<>"";ROW()<>1);MAX(INDIRECT("A1:A" & (ROW(A1)-1)))+1;IF(AND(B1<>"";ROW()=1);1;""))`
```

And I guet this dragging it down:

[image]

*How it works?*

1. The trick here is `MAX(INDIRECT("A1:A" & (ROW(A1)-1)))+1`. With INDIRECT you can reference a specific range. The index are always in column A and starts in row 1, that's why I typed `"A1:A"`. But you want to get max value from A1 to Activecell-1, that's why I added `(ROW(A1)-1)`. This will get the row number of active selection minus 1.
2. `IF(AND(B1<>"";ROW()<>1)` This is just to check if adjacent cell is not empty, and row number is different than 1. If true, then do the previous step. If false, then do step 3.
3. If the first `IF` returns False, could be because adyacent cell is empty, or because row number is 1. So we need to check that with `IF(AND(B1<>"";ROW()=1)`. If true, means B1 is not empty and row number is 1, so index **must be forced to be** 1. You cannot calculate the max value of a range previous to A1 or it will raise an error. IF this second IF returns False, means adyacent cell is empty, so we do nothing.

Comment: thx a lot! The other answer is a lot easier, but this one helps me to understand some more concepts of excel as well, so thank you very much for that!

Comment: Nice tutorial comments! *(+1)*